# Using one event to trigger multiple ajax requests in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am writing a metrics page using React-Redux, which I haven't used before, and am having trouble structuring it.

The basic structure is something like this:

```
<input id=start_date />
<input id=end_date />
<button id=submit onClick={ this.props.fetchChartData() }/>
<Chart1 />
<Chart2 />
```

The store structure is this:

```
dates
    start_date: "2016-09-16"
    end_date: "2016-09-16"
charts
    Chart1
        api_func: "get_supported_events"
        fetching: false
        fetched: false
        data: null
        error: null
    Chart2
        api_func: "get_events_closed"
        fetching: false
        fetched: false
        data: null
        error: null
```

Using thunk, my actions right now include these functions:

```
function getStateURL(state){
    return state.charts.Chart1['api_func'];
}

export function fetchChartData(){
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(fetchChartDataStart());
        return fetch(getStateURL(getState()))
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => dispatch(receiveChartData(json)))
            .catch((err) => dispatch(fetchChartDataError(err)));
    }
}
```

The problem is, I don't want to hard code the chart name because I feel like I should be able to write one action since all of the charts need to do the same thing.

The best solution I could guess is to have the button trigger an event that the chart components could listen for so that when the state is requested it is limited to the chart's portion, not the entire state. Is there a way to make a react component trigger an event that can be caught by other components?

Comment: Why not just pass  the information you need it to the fetchChartData action? Also where you are "hard coding" the chart name? Do you mean the `['api_func']` ?

Comment: So right now I'm calling fetchChartData via the button, and I need all of the charts to fetch a separate url. I want the button to be agnostic of what charts are in the application; it should just signal that all of the charts need to be updated.

The hard coding is in getStateURL, where I specify that I want Chart1's api_func.

Comment: Why not just pass all the charts and loop through them for the strings, or make your own mapping if you know all of the possible charts. Or better yet, if you have access to the back end, make it a single call that takes a list of charts as a param.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are proposing seems more like old Flux model when store was just an instance of EventEmitter.

Using Flux, you can make `<Chart />` like

```
class Chart extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    store.addEventListener('fetchData', this.fetchData);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    store.removeEventListener('fetchData', this.fetchData);
  }

  this.fetchData() {
    api.fetchChartData(store.get('chart1.url');
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

With `Redux` however it is not immediately obvious. But it is possible to do it:

```
class Chart1 extends Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (!nextProps.fetching && !nextProps.fetched) {
      const { fetchData, url } = this.props;
      fetchData(url);
    }
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({
  fetching: state.Chart1.fetching
  fetched: state.Chart1.fetched
  url: state.Chart1.url
}), {
  fetchData
})(Chart1)
```

and in `/action.js`

```
export function fetchChartData(url){
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchChartDataStart());
        return fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => dispatch(receiveChartData(json)))
            .catch((err) => dispatch(fetchChartDataError(err)));
    }
}
```

Considering the similar functionalities in all the `<Chart />` components, it's worth implementing Higher order component for this and keep url somewhere as constants rather than in store.

```
export const fetchData = (url) => (Wrapped) => {
  class Wrapper extends Component {
      componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (!nextProps.fetching && !nextProps.fetched) {
          const { fetchData, url } = this.props;
          fetchData(url);
        }
      }

      render() {
        return <Wrapped {...this.props} />
      }
  }

  return connect(null, { fetchData })(Wrapper);
}
```

In `Chart.jsx` use it like:

```
import { chart1Url } from '.../someconstants';
import { fetchData } from '/hocs/fetchData'

const Chart1 = () => {
    return <div>...</div>;
}

export default fetchData(chartUrl)(Chart1);
```

Although it is possible, I still think the best solution would be to store URLs in a constants file, and put api functions in another module. You can do something like:
./api/fetchData.js

```
export function fetchData(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => resolve(json))
      .catch((err) => reject(err));
}
```

./actions.js

```
import { fetchData } from '../api/fetchData';
import { urls } from '.../constants';

export function fetchChartData(){
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(fetchChartDataStart());
        return Promise.all(urls.map((url) =>
          fetchData(url)
            .then((json) => dispatch(receiveChartData(json)))
            .catch((err) => dispatch(fetchChartDataError(err))));
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems pretty close to what I need, trying it out now. Out of curiosity, my driving force for getting this right is so that when a new chart is requested the next dev can just drop in the new chart file they write and add the chart to the main JSX. To that end, I would just put the URL in the component itself; is there a distinct advantage to placing the URLs in a separate file?

Comment: Normally URLs being constant, it makes sense to put it in a separate file. This will separate concerns: data(url) and component itself. But these things definitely vary app by app. You as a developer would be the best judge. In your situation maybe URL inside a component make sense. But it won't be able to use Higher order component solution.